# email accounts with appengine domain

Tags: google-app-engine, email

When I used to host my "website" with GoDaddy, I used to have an email account `@myDomain.com`. Now that I have switched to app-engine, is there some way to send and receive emails with an account `@myDomain.com`? I am hoping for something similar to what GoDaddy had (i.e. similar to gmail, so to speak).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question, you need to look at Google Apps. However, you can [receive emails](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving) on your custom domain through App Engine if you want to handle them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can send/receive emails via `@myDomain.com` domain that you own using services like [SendGrid](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid) (or any other email services like Mandrill, Mailgun, Amazon SES, etc.) which will give you a quite a few features and perks including 25k free emails instead of GAE's 100.